# Why label with image and Entry widget can't be together ?? Can't solve this

Tags: python, tkinter

Hy guys please help me i have this simple code just for learn,i can see both the image "etichetta_sfondo" for the background and i can see even the entry widget, but how to put the entry widget in the middle of the image, how tu put it a bit down in the middle of the image and not just over it?

```
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import windll
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
window = Tk()
window.title("Gestione spese")
window.state("zoomed")
window.geometry("1500x770")
window.call('wm', 'iconphoto', window._w, PhotoImage(file="trasparente.png"))
testo_nuova_spesa = Entry(window,borderwidth=5,font=("Ink Free",20),width=9,bg="#f2f2f2")
testo_nuova_spesa.pack()
sfondo = PhotoImage(file="soldi.png")
etichetta_sfondo = Label(window,image=sfondo)
etichetta_sfondo.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: put `Entry` inside `Label` - use `label` instead of `window` as parent/master of `Entry` - `Entry(label,...)`

Comment: and you could use Entry with `.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')` to put in center of `Label`

Comment: if you center in window then keep  `entry = Entry(window)` and use `entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')` instead of `entry.pack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to use `place` with `relative position` (in percents)  and `anchor` in center of `Entry`

```
entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
```

and this put `Entry` in center of window

And this looks like in center of image because image is also in center of window.

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

window = tk.Tk()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="lenna.png")

label = tk.Label(window, image=img)
label.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(window, bg="white")
entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

If image is not in center then you can use `Label` as parent/master of `Entry` and `place` will place in center of `Label`.

This example puts `Entry` in center of second `Label`.

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

window = tk.Tk()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="lenna.png")

label1 = tk.Label(window, image=img)
label1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(window, image=img)
label2.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(label2, bg="white")
entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia.

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Hi furas thanks fir the help, yes i tried with place and entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center') and it works, could you explain why using simply place (x=20,y=30) for example is wrong because when i resize it's ugly, and insted using entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center') is better because it resize correctly?

Comment: well, it seems obvious. `x,y` is `static position` (in pixels) - it is not recalculated when you resize window. `relx, rely` is `relative position` (in percents) - when window changes size then position is recalculated.

Comment: Ok thanks now it seems good, tomorrow i will go on coding my program, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I mark your answer and upvote